# Excel Pivot Table: Different Subtotals for Different Value Fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot table with two summed field values. I need to subtotal the first one using sum and the second one using average. Here is the desired output:

| Region | State | SumOfSales | SumOfUnitsSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NY | 100 | 5 |
| A | NJ | 200 | 3 |
| **A Subtotal** |  | **300** | **4** |
| B | FL | 250 | 4 |
| B | GA | 300 | 2 |
| **B Subtotal** |  | **550** | **3** |

So far the closest thing I've been able to find is a custom subtotal through the field settings for Region. But this adds two rows for subtotals. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also share the source data behind that example Pivot Table?

Comment: So, is your picture the problem or the desired output? How do you get two rows for each Region in a pivot table? Are you not showing another column that would make them each distinct?

Comment: @Isolated this is the desired output. And I added a State column so the rows would be distinct. Sorry for the confusion.